# Android make a publicly viewable file

Tags: android

I want to save a txt file to the "data/package name" directory of my phone and make it so that file can be viewed with out having to root the phone or use DDMS, just plug in to the computer and open it

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but that's not possible.

If you want to store files in a place that the file can be accessed by the user or other apps, use [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: but other apps have files that are accessible in this area, and I can not use external storage since there is no SD slot

Comment: @JacobLawton - Which apps?

Comment: @JacobLawton: "but other apps have files that are accessible in this area" -- presumably, you are looking at external storage. "I can not use external storage since there is no SD slot" -- external storage is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: then how do I use external storage since 'getExternalStorageDirectory()' just gives me /storage/emulated/0 which I can not access

Comment: @JacobLawton: Please explain, in detail, what "I can not access" means. The root paths that you get in your app will be different than the paths that users see. `getExternalStorageDirectory()` will map to whatever shows up when the user plugs their device in via a USB cable. Please note that most locations on external storage require permissions, such as `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I have more information on this stuff in the blog posts that I linked to in the answer and first comment.